# spark-sql from_avro does not exist

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-avro

I create a sparkSession with Pyspark version 3.5.0 in the following way:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("KafkaStreamingExample") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.5.0") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

If I do a read config, it shows, that the class is loaded:

```
print(spark.conf.get("spark.jars.packages"))
org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.5.0
```

Read a stream from Kafka:

```
df_customers = (spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "broker:29092")
  .option("subscribe", "postgres.public.customers")
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .load()
)
```

And can see the output as binaries:

```
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
from time import sleep

while True:
    clear_output(wait=True)
    display(query.status)
    display(spark.sql('SELECT * from customers_query order by offset desc').show())
    sleep(10)
```

Example:

```
{'message': 'Processing new data',
 'isDataAvailable': True,
 'isTriggerActive': True}
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
|                 key|               value|               topic|partition|offset|           timestamp|timestampType|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
|[00 00 00 00 01 4...|[00 00 00 00 02 0...|postgres.public.c...|        0| 17051|2023-12-08 09:57:...|            0|
|[00 00 00 00 01 4...|[00 00 00 00 02 0...|postgres.public.c...|        0| 17050|2023-12-08 09:57:...|            0|
|[00 00 00 00 01 4...|[00 00 00 00 02 0...|postgres.public.c...|        0| 17049|2023-12-08 09:57:...|            0|
|[00 00 00 00 01 4...|[00 00 00 00 02 0...|postgres.public.c...|        0| 17048|2023-12-08 09:57:...|            0|
|[00 00 00 00 01 4...|[00 00 00 00 02 0...|postgres.public.c...|        0| 17047|2023-12-08 09:57:...|            0|
|[00 00 00 00 01 4...|[00 00 00 00 02 0...|postgres.public.c...|        0| 17046|2023-12-08 09:57:...|            0|
```

But when I try to decode the values using from_avro it fails with the message:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.avro.functions.from_avro. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method from_avro([class org.apache.spark.sql.Column, class java.util.HashMap, class java.util.HashMap]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:321)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:342)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:276)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I don't understand why. I call the function from_avro in the following way:

Read the schema:

```
topic = "postgres.public.customers-value"
#SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL = "http://172.22.0.4:8081"
SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL = "http://schema-registry:8081"
print("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: ", SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL)
URL = SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL + '/subjects/' + topic + '/versions/latest/schema'
r = requests.get(url=URL)
schema = r.json()
```

Deserialise:

```
while True:
    clear_output(wait=True)
    display(query.status)
    display(spark.sql(from_avro(data=col("value"), jsonFormatSchema=schema)).show())
    sleep(10)
```

Even a simple version `output = df_customers.select(from_avro("value", schema))`is not finding the function. I don't understand why.

Comment: 1) You cannot mix Spark package versions (replace 3.1.2) 2) from_avro won't work with the schema registry directly. You'll need to substring the byte slice first

Comment: thanks, but using the same versions like:
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.0,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.5.0") will still lead to ad "Method does not exist" error: 
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.avro.functions.from_avro. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method from_avro([class org.apache.spark.sql.Column, class java.util.HashMap, class java.util.HashMap]) does not exist

Comment: How are you running the Spark code? With spark-submit? Have you tried passing `--packages` there? Otherwise, I think calling `getOrCreate` is doing the getting part with whatever packages it currently has, rather than creating with new ones (you should see download events in the Spark logs). Jupyter kernel, for example, may preload a Spark session

Comment: Otherwise, the error is saying the arguments you're passing to the method are incorrect. The docs don't include keyword arguments on the parameters to from_avro https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html And your schema should be a string, not a dict, so you'll need to use requests text function not json (that's why the error says Hashmap class is used)